# How to set up a sticky footer background which is overlapped by the main content?

Tags: html, css, position, footer, sticky-footer

I am building a site which has a background image at the bottom. This should effectively be a sticky footer whereby it sits at the bottom of the viewport if the page content is short but will move down below the viewport bottom if the content is longer. This can be done without a problem however I want the content to be able to overlap the footer image to a certain point. So if the footer image is 100px in height for example (and the content is long enough) I would want the footer stuck to the bottom of the viewport with the content overlapping it by 80px (leaving a 20px gap at the bottom). If the content is longer than this then the footer should move down below the viewport bottom so there is still a 20px space between the bottom of the content and the end of the footer. I'm probably being stupid but I can't work out how to do this and would be most grateful if someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much!

Dave

Comment: Could you show some code on what you've tried?

Comment: Start here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Pedryk I have not actually tried anything as yet, I was just trying to work out first conceptually the best way to achieve it!

Comment: @Niels I have checked that out previously and other similar versions which are do most of what I want (and all of what I usually want!) but the content doesn't overlap the footer. If you mess with the margins to make this happen then there ends up being space between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the viewport? Unless i'm missing something which is distinctly possible :) Thanks

Comment: @Niels I obviously didn't look closely enough, you can actually just decrease the height of the push div which will change how much the content overlaps the footer, that's absolutely perfect, thanks for so much for making me take another look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I obviously didn't look closely enough, you can actually just decrease the height of the push div which will change how much the content overlaps the footer, that's absolutely perfect, thanks for so much for making me take another look!